# Audio Picker In Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, audio, picker

I need to pick an audio from the iOS device storage, and then play the audio. I can play the audio using the AVFoundation. But I could not find any library to pick the audio file from the phone storage(something like a UIImagePicker for Images). Is there any library which will help me choose audio files from an iOS device?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "audio picker" in iOS.

You can use `MPMediaPickerController` to allow the user to select audio files from their own media library.

You can use `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to let users select files from iCloud or other Cloud services they have in use (Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.). Just specify appropriate audio UTIs.

But there is no way to select random audio files stored within other apps.

Comment: I have seen in a couple of apps that we can choose mp3 files from the iTunes library. How can we acc Ss the iTunes library, if not access the phone storage for voice memos?

Comment: The 2nd sentence of my answer tells you how to access songs from the iTunes library.

Comment: I can see why this answer not accepted, not code no party.